# SSRS set parameters value based on another parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have seven parameters with values 1,2,3,4,5. When I set first(general) param at '2' all parameters should set it too. But they still should be able to choose another values without changing another params.

Comment: This can be done for the first time the user makes a choice for the first parameter. Further changes in the first parameter will not update the rest.

Comment: No it isnt. Params changes "almost" every time when I change first param. It have bug sometimes and params dont changes.

Comment: it works every time, when i use a additional param. This param is equal to first param. But when I hide(or set "internal") it - values changing doesnt work more.

Comment: I have done what you are asking by using an intermediate parameter, but hiding it or making it internal caused the rest parameters not updating when the first changed.